# Python: Urllib2 | [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I'm calling a list of urls from the same domain and returning a snip of their html for a few thousand domains but am getting this error about 1,000 rows or so in.

- Is there anything I can do to avoid this error?
- Does it make sense to create a wait step after every row? every few hundred rows?
- Is there a better way to get around this?

  ```
    File "/Users.../ap.py", line 144, in <module> simpleProg()
    File "/Users.../ap.py", line 21, in simpleProg()
    File "/Users.../ap.py", line 57, in first_step()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
      return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
      response = self._open(req, data)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open 
      '_open', req)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
      return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
      r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
      response.begin()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
      version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
      line = self.fp.readline()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 447, in readline
      data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
      socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
  ```

Comment: the server refuses your requests, probably because they are way too many. add a time.sleep() between calls

Comment: is 1-2 seconds enough or should I be bumping that up pretty high, generally?

Comment: try with 1 sec first and see what happens